# Can I change the brightness and contrast of an image before cropping it with ngx-image-cropper?

Tags: html, angular, brightness, css-filters, ngx-image-cropper

**Question** - Is there any easy way (ex. CSS) to change the brightness and contrast of an image before sending it to [ngx-image-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper), so that when I call crop() the brightness/contrast persist to the final cropped output image?

Ex. load it into a viewer (ex. img tag), adjust brightness, then load it into the cropper window, adjust the zoom, cropped area, etc, then call crop() on the image to get the final output.

**Problem** - Nothing I'm trying seems to work to change the brightness of the final cropped image output and I'm aware the ngx-image-cropper library doesn't allow me to adjust brightness or contrast. I can only zoom and rotate. I'm also aware there are other libraries to do this, I'm stuck on finding one for Angular that is easy free and simple to use.

I have created and set up a [Stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-image-cropper-example-sjqmd6?file=src/app/app.component.html) to show the process I use to get and crop an image.

Maybe I need to rethink the way I'm working with and editing an image, while using the cropper library?

Here is the code to demo the process

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild(ImageCropperComponent) imageCropper: ImageCropperComponent;
  name = 'Angular';
  imageChangedEvent: any = '';
    croppedImage: any = '';
    
    fileChangeEvent(event: any): void {
        this.imageChangedEvent = event;
    }
    imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
        // this.croppedImage = event.base64;
    }
    load() {
        const croppedImageEvent = this.imageCropper.crop();
        this.croppedImage = croppedImageEvent.base64;
    }
    imageLoaded() {
        // show cropper
    }
    cropperReady() {
        // cropper ready
    }
    loadImageFailed() {
        // show message
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />

<image-cropper
    [imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
    [maintainAspectRatio]="true"
    [aspectRatio]="3 / 2"
    [resizeToWidth]="300"
    format="png"
    (imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
    (imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
    (cropperReady)="cropperReady()"
    (loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"
></image-cropper>
<div style="padding-bottom: 1rem">
    <input type="button" value="Load cropped image" (click)="load()" />
</div>

<img [src]="croppedImage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

[ngx-image-cropper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-cropper) only supports cropping related features. It doesn't come with other features such as brightness or contrast adjustment.

One of the popular paid library is [pintura](https://pqina.nl/pintura/) which supports Angular out of the box.

If you are only interested in open-source library, then this site has a good list: https://medevel.com/16-os-photo-image-editors/

Comment: ya it looks like pintura has a lot more features than I need and it's very expensive. I really only need 2 more features on top of what ngx-image-cropper gives me (brightness, contrast) and maybe a 3rd feature like sepia or something that I can use in conjunction with the others to enhance the image.

Comment: Have you used CamanJS. It seems pretty good but it doesn't have any Angular port and I read that it's not supported anymore.

Comment: @user1186050 CamanJS and DarkroomJS alike are no longer maintained for almost 10 years. You can try [Tui Image Editor](https://github.com/nhn/tui.image-editor#-documents). They seem to have Angular wrapper for it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tui-image-editor-angular

Comment: this might sound like a stupid question, but will I have any issues using this in a Angular application if I use the Javascript version and not the Angular wrapper?

Comment: @user1186050 No question is stupid question, and your question is a great one. I think you can use a JavaScript version with Angular, but the library needs to have the `xxxx.d.ts` or you need to see if the `xxx.d.ts` file is available somewhere to be download. This file is used by the compiler to understand and know what type to expect.

Comment: I see a index.d.ts file that has lots of interfaces. Is that it or should there be more than 1?

Comment: @user1186050 It might be it. You will need to play around with it. If you feel like helping the community, maybe you can try integrating the Lib into a new Angular app, then push it to GitHub. I might be able to collaborate with you, but I can't promise that.

Comment: I would have no idea how to do that...right now I'm just looking for the quickest, and simplest way to crop, adjust brightness and contrast, zoom, and rotate an image so I can upload it to Cloudinary. The faster I can do this, the faster I can move on to more complicated issues in the app. I'm looking at just using a canvas tag and doing it with vanilla JS, or I'll try Toast UI photo editor with JS.

Comment: Do you know what I'm doing wrong here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71701917/1186050

Comment: @user1186050 I responded.

Comment: What if you create your own? I mean you can add 2 range inputs values that bind to the CSS brightness and contrast values.  Something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-image-cropper-example-akgqg4?file=src/app/app.component.css