# How do I import TUI image editor for Javascript into my Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, node-modules

**Problem** - I have an Angular app and I want to use [Toast UI image editor](https://nhn.github.io/tui.image-editor/latest/#typescript)
but I'm not sure how to add the imports to app.module.ts so that I can use it?

I followed the install instructions for npm

```
$ npm install --save tui-image-editor
```

and it looks like it installed ok with 1 deprecated dependancy.

In the Toast UI page I see this image below but not sure what they mean by

> "import module = require('module') on importing. export = and import = require()"

[image]

I tried to add this line below to my app.module.ts file to get the reference to the node module but I'm seeing an error that says

> This module can only be referenced with ECMAScript imports/exports by turning on the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag and referencing its default export

```
import * as index from 'tui-image-editor';
import * as index from 'tui-image-editor/index'; // tried this too
```

I also tried this below, but got the error saying "Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead"

```
import module = require('module')
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are getting this error is that the Library is a `CommonJS` instead of an `ES Modules` type.

In order to use this library, you will need to do the following:

1. Add the following to `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
"compilerOptions": {

    ...//other stuffs

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true <========== This
}
```

2. Import it into the component you want to use (NOT in the `app.module.ts`). In this case, I use `app.component.ts`:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import ImageEditor from 'tui-image-editor'; // <========= THIS

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  private _tuiImageEditor!: ImageEditor;

  // Angular way of getting the element without getElementById.
  @ViewChild('tuiRef')
  private _tuiRef!: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this._createImageEditor();
  }

  private _createImageEditor() {

    this._tuiImageEditor = new ImageEditor(this._tuiRef.nativeElement, {
      cssMaxWidth: 700,
      cssMaxHeight: 500
    });

    // Add a picture into your assets folder to test.
    this._tuiImageEditor.loadImageFromURL('../assets/example.jpg', 'My example picture');
  }

}
```

3. Then you will need to add this to your `app.component.html`

```
<h3>TUI Image Editor: </h3>

<div #tuiRef style="height: 800px">
  <canvas></canvas>
</div>
```

You will notice the warning when you do `ng serve`. That's because `commonJS` is slow, and we should avoid using them if possible in Angular.